# Failed building wheel for Levenshtein

Tags: python, pip, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy

I am trying to install Levenshtein and Fuzzy on my laptop, but for a reason, that I don't understand i get: Failed building wheel for Levenshtein and the same error for Fuzzy every time.

I have windows 10 64bit and Python 3.6 on my system.

I would appreciate it if somebpdy could help me with concrete hint, if he/she experiencd such an error.

[image: first_pic]
[image: second pic]
[image: third_pic]

Comment: can you add the stack trace for when the install fails?

Comment: We can't help if we don't have sufficient context to recreate and/or see the error being thrown. A Stack Trace is helpful when debugging built-in tools, since this is not a code issue, but more a python environment and os issue

Comment: @shafigh: Copy & paste the actual text of the error.  Do not post images of text.

Answer (score 3):

It tells you in your StackTrace what to do:

`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required`

Follow those instructions to download it (via the github link in the StackTrace)